# Checking multiple columns for one value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I have a table that has columns like this for example:

```
id,col1,col2,col3,col4
```

Now, I want to check if `ANY` of `col1, col2, col3, col4` have the passed in value.

The long way to do it would be..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = 123 OR col2 = 123 OR col3 = 123 OR col4 = 123);
```

I guess it's the opposite version of `IN`.

Is there an easier way to do what I want?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use the `IN` predicate, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 123 IN(col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad038/1)

---

> it's the opposite version of IN.

**No it is not**, It is the same as using the `OR`s the way you did in your question.

---

### To clarify this:

The predicate `IN` or set membership is defined as<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Where the `Value Expression` can be either <sup>2</sup>:

[image]

So it is fine to do it this way, using the value expression `123`, which is a literal.

---

<sup>1, 2: <sup>Images from: [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433362)</sup></sup>

Comment: How to pass more than one value as values to search for? for example "123" and "456".

Comment: @AlagesanPalani - The same way: `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE columnName IN (123, 456');`

Comment: no, i want something like select * from tablename where '123','456' in(col1,col2,col3)

Comment: i use **set `uid1`=IF(`uid1` IS NULL, IF ('@myUniqueID' not in (uid2,uid3,uid4),'@myUniqueID', NULL ), `uid1`)** but not work

Comment: Excellent solution. It worked. I can't believe that I never tried this before.

Comment: Is it also possible to find the "col1, col2, col3, col4" first with a subquery, and use that result?

Something like this for a subquery:  SELECT ALL COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tableschema'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_ID'

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like: (Note: Assuming the columns are numeric values. And, just incase the concatenated value creates the character sequence you are looking for, use a delimiter to distinguish the column values.  Pipe (|) is the delimiter in this example.)

```
SELECT [ID]
    ,[Col1]
    ,[Col2]
    ,[Col3]
    ,[Col4]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE '123' IN (
    CAST([Col1] AS VARCHAR) + '|'
    + CAST([Col2] AS VARCHAR) + '|'
    + CAST([Col3] AS VARCHAR) + '|'
    + CAST([Col4] AS VARCHAR) + '|'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 OR col2 IN(SELECT xid FROM tablex WHERE somecol = 3)
```

Not sure if it is "the best way" but it works for me.

Comment: This actually DOES work, even with in....Thank you!

Example: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (owner_id, user_id) IN (1, 2, 3);

Comment: `col1 OR col2` doesn't do what you think it does. This query also returns any row where `col1` is truthy.

Comment: [It should only select rows "two", "three", "four", but it also selects "one"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hxezgYkJT9Fc7xPFp6Z49r/2)