# What's the optimal way to check multiple columns for a single record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a select all statement that checks multiple columns in a single row for one value and if it doesn't have the value then exclude it from the query?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [questions/13916400/checking-multiple-columns-for-one-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916400/checking-multiple-columns-for-one-value).

Comment: Do all columns have to have that value or at least one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply by reversing the normal `in` operator: `value in (column1, column2, column3)`

Comment: Ah this got it! Thanks Allan! Yeah I haven't used sql in awhile, still a little rusty!

Answer (score 1):

Use a "reversed" IN():

```
select ....
from ...
where someValue in ( col1, col2, col3, ...)
```