# How to extract data from Column where the records are equal to 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I'll try to explain you the problem of mine. I'm searching for advice because I'm in impasse.
I have this database for an online store (it doesn't sell anything, it's just to show people owner's products).

I have two (they are more, but for this situation we'll consider just two of them) table. In the first:

```
products name | gender | id_product | etc..

    john        male     23
```

In the second:

```
id_product | man_56 | man_54 | man_52 | man_50 | etc...

 23         0         1       0        1
```

`id_product` is the same as the first table. It's used to link the two table. Also `1=available, 0=not available`).

Screenshot:

[image]

Now I don't know how to select/print only the column where records are 1 and not 0. Do I need to specify every column's name of the table?

Comment: You need to explain this question a lot more. For a start, showing more than one row of data, plus your desired outcome would help

Comment: Ok. I've taken a screen of my table to show you how it's thought: http://i63.tinypic.com/15i59h4.png

The result should be(it should print only where column_name=1):
For id_product 15
Avaliable size: Woman: 40, 42
For id_product=12
Avaliable size: Children 7, 9

Comment: Looks like you comment got cut - please edit your question with the details

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've completed it right now

Comment: Well the proper way to do it would be to normalize your database. However with that data structure you would be best off just selecting the whole row, then checking if each value == 1 before printing

Comment: What do you mean "normalize"? Thanks for the advice

Comment: Well, thats a big subject you would need to google, but in this case, it means breaking your problem down into 3 tables instead of two: your products table, as it is, a 'productAttributes' table that contains 2 columns : attributeID and description, (eg: `1 | men_42`,`2 | men44` etc) and  3rd table: `products_attributes` that contains a link between the two tables with columns productID and attributeID columns.

Comment: Thanks, I'll google and  then I'll improve it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT * from tablename where columname = 1
```

tablename is your name of table i.e products
columnname is the name of feild which you want to check.

Comment: Yes, but when 'columname' are more than one?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 IN (ColumnOne,ColumnTwo,ColumnThree...)
```

For more info, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916400/checking-multiple-columns-for-one-value)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved  my problem using multiple "if". Thanks to all of you :D