# Reversed "IN" operator? Is that possible?

Tags: mysql

Is it legit to switch operands in "IN" operator in MySQL? Just like that:

1. Normal "IN" operator: *column_name IN (value1,value2,...)*
2. Perversed "IN" operator: *value IN (column_name1,column_name2,...)*

...thus effectively replacing multiple "OR" operators.

Comment: You should be able to do that.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yep. Perfectly legit. E.g. `WHERE 'Ali' IN (first_name,last_name)`

Comment: ....but implies bad database design (not normalized)

Comment: Yes I tried and it worked fine, but how the database engine will distinguish between column names and string literals? I assume column names need proper escaping?

Comment: @symcbean I disagree, as I think my example demonstrates.

Comment: @symcbean `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 123 IN (id, parent)` should select user with id 123 and all his children. I think it's perfectly normal.

Comment: @SergeyDanilchenko: String literals are in *quotes*.  Column names are *unquoted* (or wrapped in backticks `\``).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - just as described in this question: [Checking multiple columns for one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916400/checking-multiple-columns-for-one-value) (sorry, can't flag question as duplicate, my flag count is over).